# How to get the future level from an ets() forecast in R

Tags: r, forecasting, forecast

Given the following code I can obtain the "fitted" level.

```
fit <- ets(USAccDeaths)
fit$states[,"l"]
```

I would like to get the future forecasted level. The problem is the "states" object in the forecast object does not have the forecasted level.

```
fcast <- forecast(fit, h = 3)
fcast$model$states
```

How can I get the forecasted level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation for the level includes the forecast error at that time. Since you don't know the forecast error until you observe an actual, you can't know the level for future times.

Forecasts from ETS models use the final value of each state in the forecast equation. So if you want a forecast of the level, use the last observed value.